# How to simulate long running process in .NET API Controller Correctly

Tags: c#, .net, api, unit-testing, parallel-processing

I am trying to create a unit test to simulate my API being called by many people at the same time.

I've got this code in my unit test:

```cs
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var id = i; // must assign to new variable inside for loop
                var t = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    response = await Client.GetAsync("/api/test2?id=" + id);
                    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
                });
                tasks.Add(t);
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Then in my controller I am putting in a `Thread.Sleep`.
But when I do this, the total time for all tests to complete is 10 x the sleep time.

I expected all the calls to be made and to have ended up at the `Thread.Sleep` call at more or less the same time.

But it seems the API calls are actually made one after the other.

The reason I am testing the parallel API call is because I want to test a deadlock issue with my data repository when using SQLite which has only happened when more than 1 user uses my website at the same time.

And I have never been able to simulate this and I thought I'd create a unit test, but the code I have now seems to not be executing the calls in parallel.

My plan with the Thread.Sleep calls was to put a couple in the Controller method to make sure all requests end up between certain code blocks at the same time.

Do I need to set a a max number of parallel requests on the Web Server or something or am I doing something obviously wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**Update 1:**
I forgot to mention I get the same results with `await Task.Delay(1000);` and many similar alternatives.

Not sure if it's clear but this is all running within a unit test using NUnit.
And the "Web Server" and Client is created like this:

```cs
            var builder = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<TStartup>();           
            Server = new TestServer(builder);
            Client = Server.CreateClient();
```

Comment: Load testing isn't trivial. Have you considered using a tool like k6?

Comment: are you sure that the server isnt the one doing them in series

Comment: @pm100 what do you mean if the server is doing them in series?  
It is doing them in series but I can't figure out why, that is my problem.
Is there a setting perhaps to set that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with my test.
It was not the TestServer or the client code, it was the Database code.

In my controller I was starting an NHibernate Transaction, and that was blocking the requests because it would put a lock on the table being updated.

This is correct, so I had to change my code a bit to not automatically start a transaction. But rather leave that up to the calling code to manage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Task.Delay(time in milliseconds)`. `Thread.Sleep` will not release a thread and it can't process other tasks while waiting to result.

Comment: I forgot to mention, i get the same results with await Task.Delay and pretty much all alternatives like that I could find.

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpClient` class in .NET has a limit of two concurrent requests to the same server by default, which I believe might be causing the issue in this case. Usually, this limit can be overridden by creating a new `HttpClientHandler` and using it as an argument in the constructor:

```
new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
            {
                MaxConnectionsPerServer = 100
            })
```

But because the clients are created using the `TestServer` method, that gets a little more complicated. You could try changing the `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` property like below, but I'm not sure if that will work with the `TestServer`:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
```

That being said, I believe using Unit Tests for doing load testing is not a good approach and recommend looking into tools specific for load testing.

- [Reference for `ServicePointManagerClass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Net_ServicePointManager_DefaultConnectionLimit)
- [This blog post also has more in-depth information about the subject](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclient-connection-pooling-in-dotnet-core)

Comment: Will try this a bit later.
I'm not really trying to do load testing, just want a way to test simulating the DB being access from 2 requests at more or less the same time.